# Issue converting a python program to cython for speedup

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, cython, sparse-matrix

I am trying to write a fast algorithm in Cython.  The algorithm is fairly straightforward and is described here (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4357.pdf - the paragraph before Theorem 8 on page 17).  The idea is relatively straightforward: assuming that the data is sparse it can be given as input in the form `(i,j,A_ij)` for a matrix `A` which has n rows and d columns.  Now to take advantage of the sparsity we need two functions `h` which maps the n rows into s buckets uniformly at random (which is a parameter to the algorithm) and a sign function `s` which is just ±1 with equal probability.  Then for every triple `(i,j,A_ij)` the algorithm must output `(h(i),j, s(h(i))*A_ij)` and return these as arrays to be given as input to another sparse.

The problem is that I can't get a speedup.  This should run extremely fast and outperform matrix multiplication of realising S and multiplying by A as illustrated in the above reference.

Python approach (roughly 11ms):

```
    import numpy as np
    import numpy.random as npr
    from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
    def countSketch_faster(input_matrix, sketch_size, seed=None):
        '''
        input_matrix: sparse - coo_matrix type
        sketch_size: int
        seed=None : random seed
        '''
        observed_rows = set([])
        sign_hashes = []
        hash_table = {}
        sketched_data = []
        hashed_rows = []


        for row_id, col_id, Aij in zip(input_matrix.row, input_matrix.col, input_matrix.data):
            if row_id in observed_rows:
                sketched_data.append(hash_table[row_id][1]*Aij)
                hashed_rows.append(hash_row_val)
            else:
                hash_row_val, sign_val = np.random.choice(sketch_size), np.random.choice([-1.0,1.0])
                hash_table[row_id] = (hash_row_val, sign_val) #hash-sign pair
                sketched_data.append(sign_val*Aij)
                hashed_rows.append(hash_row_val)
                observed_rows.add(row_id)


    hashed_rows = np.asarray(hashed_rows)
    sketched_data = np.asarray(sketched_data)
    row_hashes = np.asarray(row_hashes)

    S = coo_matrix((sketched_data, (hashed_rows, input_matrix.col))).tocsr()
    return S
```

Converting to Cython:
Analysing the annotated output highlights that the most python-heavy lines are those which call numpy.  I have tried to `cdef` all variables and specify `dtype` for any call to numpy.  Also, I have removed the `zip` command and tried to keep the loop simpler and more C-like.  All of this has actually had an adverse effect though and it runs very slowly, and I'm not really sure why.  It seems like quite a simple algorithm to implement so if someone could help me get the runtime down to something very small I would be extremely grateful.

```
%%cython --annotate
cimport cython
import numpy.random as npr
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

 def countSketch_cython(input_matrix, sketch_size, seed=None):
    '''
    input_matrix: sparse - coo_matrix type
    sketch_size: int
    seed=None : random seed
    '''

    cdef Py_ssize_t idx
    cdef int row_id
    cdef float data_id
    cdef float sketch_data_val
    cdef int hash_row_value
    cdef float sign_value



    hash_table = {}
    sketched_data = np.zeros_like(input_matrix.data,dtype=np.float64)
    hashed_rows = np.zeros_like(sketched_data,dtype=np.float64)
    observed_rows = set([])

    for idx in range(input_matrix.row.shape[0]):
        row_id = input_matrix.row[idx]
        data_id = input_matrix.data[idx]

        if row_id in observed_rows:
            hash_row_value = hash_table[row_id][0]
            sign_value = hash_table[row_id][1]
            sketched_data[row_id] = sign_value*data_id
            hashed_rows[idx] = hash_row_value
        else:
            hash_row_val = np.random.randint(low=0,high=sketch_size+1)
            sign_val = np.random.choice([-1.0,1.0])
            hash_table[row_id] = (hash_row_val, sign_val) #hash-sign pair
            sketched_data[idx] = sign_val*data_id
            hashed_rows[idx] = hash_row_value
            observed_rows.add(row_id)


    S = coo_matrix((sketched_data, (hashed_rows, input_matrix.col)))
return S`
```

UPDATE: I have managed to speed the code up by removing some of the slower lines.  These were calls to `np.random` for which the C random number generator was faster, giving the length in the input so this did not need to be calculated, and not converting to a sparse matrix before returning (for the purpose of this experiment I am interested in how quickly the transform can be done as opposed to details surrounding the conversion for downstream use).

%%cython --annotate
    cimport cython
    import numpy.random as npr
    import numpy as np
    from libc.stdlib cimport rand

```
#@cython.boundscheck(False)  # these don't contribute much in this
```

example
    #@cython.wraparound(False)
     def countSketch(input_matrix, input_matrix_length, sketch_size, seed=None):
         '''
         input_matrix: sparse - coo_matrix type
         input_matrix_length - number of rows in input matrix
         sketch_size: int
         seed=None : random seed
        '''

```
    cdef Py_ssize_t idx
    cdef int row_id
    cdef float data_id
    cdef float sketch_data_val
    cdef int hash_row_value
    cdef float sign_value
    cdef int arr_lengths = input_matrix_length

    # These two lines are still annotated most boldly
    cdef double[:,:] sketched_data = 
np.zeros((arr_lengths,1),dtype=np.float64)
    cdef double[:,:] hashed_rows = np.zeros((arr_lengths,1))

    hash_table = {}

    observed_rows = set([])

    for idx in range(arr_lengths):
        row_id = input_matrix.row[idx]
        data_id = input_matrix.data[idx]

        if row_id in observed_rows:
            hash_row_value = hash_table[row_id][0]
            sign_value = hash_table[row_id][1]
            sketched_data[row_id] = sign_value*data_id
            hashed_rows[idx] = hash_row_value
        else:
            hash_row_val = rand()%(sketch_size) 
            #np.random.randint(low=0,high=sketch_size+1)
            sign_val = 2*rand()%(2) - 1
            #np.random.choice([-1.0,1.0])
            hash_table[row_id] = (hash_row_val, sign_val) #hash-sign pair
            sketched_data[idx] = sign_val*data_id
            hashed_rows[idx] = hash_row_value
            observed_rows.add(row_id)


    #S = coo_matrix((sketched_data, (hashed_rows, input_matrix.col)), dtype=np.float64) 
return hashed_rows, sketched_data
```

On a random sparse matrix `A = scipy.sparse.random(1000, 50, density=0.1)` this now achieves `508 µs ± 17.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)` using `%timeit countSketch(A, A.shape[0],100)`.  I should imagine there are still gains to be made as I don't know if I have set the arrays in the best way.

Comment: When you say "the most python-heavy lines are those which call numpy", which lines are you talking about? And by "python-heavy", what exactly do you mean? Lots of CPU time spent doing Python operations? Because if you're talking about the lines that build giant arrays out of giant lists… that time is already all inside numpy, so you can't speed it up; the answer is to just build up arrays instead of lists in the first place.

Comment: Essentially anything which is `np.` comes up extremely yellow on the annotated html.  It is discussed here in the Primes section: http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html

Comment: I am also open to a slightly different implementation if anything comes to mind but this was the best I could come up with in python before moving across to cython.

Comment: If you're just calling a numpy function on a numpy array, you can ignore the annotation. If you're calling a numpy function on a large non-numpy value, then the problem it's telling you about is real, but it can only be solved by not doing that, because all the slowdown is actually happening inside numpy, as it processes that large value. You seem to be already trying to cut down such things (e.g., building `hashed_rows` as an np.array of np.float64 instead of a list of floats), but that doesn't mean you caught all of them.

Comment: Hold on a second: is that `cdef Py_ssize_, idx` typo in your code? I don't know exactly why it isn't a syntax error, my guess is that it declares `Py_ssize_` as a C int, and then just does nothing at all with `idx`, instead of declaring `idx` as a `Py_ssize_t`, which is what you almost certainly wanted. Which then means that your loop is using a Python object for `idx` rather than a C int, and you're boxing and unboxing all over the place.

Comment: Yes that is a typo (it should read Py_ssize_t) and that did make a difference - thanks.

Comment: If that solves your problem, then we can close this as a typo question. (Unless you don't understand why, in which case I can answer it by explaining that.) If, after fixing that, things are not as bad, but it's still not enough to solve the problem, please re-verify the Cython annotation and whatever benchmarking/profiling you did, so we know for sure we're looking at the right things. (Also, if you could update your question to tell us exactly which lines were annotated, that would help.)

Comment: You can probably generate all your random numbers at once - make a big buffer of sign_val = np.random.choice([0,1], size = arrlengths) and iterate along it, instead of generating on demand. for my code, this was a large speed up, not sure how it would compate to using rand() though